# In my navbar I have a submenu when I click on one submenu its redirecting me to its inner submenu page

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my navbar there is a project submenu completed and ongoing both two are also a submenus containing abc project for completed submenu and ongoing submenu consist bcd project. when I click on completed its shows the abc project and when I click on ongoing its shows the bcd project but also redirect me to the page of bcd project .So the problem is I want bcd project page to appear only when I click on bcd project 'a' tag not on ongoing submenu click.it work fine for completed submenu. The flow should be I click on project menu then ongoing menu and then bcd project then clicking bcd project redirecting me to its page. but the flow here is project -> ongoing->redirecting to bcd project. On going menu also work when I first click on it , it doent redirect me but if I first open completed menu and then ongoing menu the problem is coming.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top probootstrap-navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" title="uiCookies:FineOak"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar-collapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown" >
              <a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Projects</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                <!-- <form> -->
                <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown" >
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><span>Completed</span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="portfolio-single.html">ABC Project</a></li>                   
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><span>Ongoing</span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="portfolio-2.html">BCD Project</a></li>
          
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- </form> -->
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Career</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--TO PREVENT CLOSING OF MAIN MENU WHEN CLICKED ON SUB MENU  -->
<script>
  $('ul.dropdown-menu').on('click', function (event) {
      // The event won't be propagated up to the document NODE and 
      // therefore delegated events won't be fired
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your complete code and your output in the code snippet? why does your code start with a `li` tag?

Comment: please check the edited code

Comment: Thanks. when I click on `ongoing` not occur no event. do you use `jquery`? I don't know about it.